# VS2019 : Error encountered while pushing to the remote repository: Git failed with a fatal error. unable to access

Tags: git, visual-studio-2019

Today my visual studio 2019 team explorer github push get below error.
I have no idea how to fix this error.

error message :

```
Pushing master
Error encountered while pushing to the remote repository: Git failed with a fatal error.
unable to access 'https://github.com/xxxxxxx.git': error setting certificate verify locations:
  CAfile: c:/program files (x86)/microsoft visual studio/2019/community/common7/ide/commonextensions/microsoft/teamfoundation/team explorer/Git/mingw32/bin/curl-ca-bundle.crt
  CApath: none
Pushing to https://github.com/xxxxxxx.git
```

[image: image-20200820161839927]

[image: image-20200820161904353]

my git version :

```
$ git --version
git version 2.17.1.windows.2
```

my `C:\ProgramData\Git\config` :

```
[core]
    symlinks = false
    autocrlf = true
    fscache = true
[color]
    diff = auto
    status = auto
    branch = auto
    interactive = true
[help]
    format = html
[rebase]
    autosquash = true
```

---

update :

I checked no file at `C:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2019\community\common7\ide\commonextensions\microsoft\teamfoundation\team explorer\Git\mingw32\bin\curl-ca-bundle.crt`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In case you encounter this error after you uninstalled "Git for Windows", make sure you delete the folder "C:\Program Files\Git" manually. The uninstall process leaves a "gitconfig" file in "C:\Program Files\Git\etc" that is picked up by Visual Studio and is causing issues in conjunction with the "OpenSSL" value in the "Cryptographic network provider" setting. As a workaround, it is also possible to change the value to "Secure Channel" instead.

[image: Visual Studio Git Global Settings]

Comment: This lead me to the answer I accidentally uninstalled git for windows

Answer (score 1):

follow this page [fatal: unable to access curl-ca-bundle.crt · Issue #4836 · desktop/desktop](https://github.com/desktop/desktop/issues/4836)

1. I found `curl-ca-bundle.crt` at `C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\curl-ca-bundle.crt`
2. copy it to `C:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2019\community\common7\ide\commonextensions\microsoft\teamfoundation\team explorer\Git\mingw32\bin\curl-ca-bundle.crt`
3. try to push in vs2019 and it's work.

[image: image-20200820163528852]

[image: image-20200820163726502]